# Access id of ajaxForm element

Tags: jquery, upload, progress-bar, jquery-forms-plugin, identify

I need to access the `id` of the `form` element with `class="ajax-upload-image"`. I have several of these `forms`, with the same `class`, which is why I need to access the `id`, but it seems like I cannot get the right values using `$(this)`. I need this value in both `beforeSend`, `uploadProgress`, and `complete`.

Is there some way to save a custom variable, or extract it through the `data` being sent? My current "solution" is to store a global varible with the id last accessed, but that is hardly a solution, since it is possible to use the forms before the previous are done uploading, which mean a change in the global variable.

My stripped code so far (without the global variable):

```
$('.ajax-upload-image').ajaxForm({
    delegation: true,
    dataType: 'json',

    beforeSend: function() {
        // Some code
    },

    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        // Some code
    },

    complete: function(data) {
        // Some code
    }
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated, since I seem to be very stuck at this point.

Comment: why isn't global variables working? works even if they are sent simultaneously! `var that=this;`

Comment: @AminJafari I need to have a dynamic number of these, with no limit. Global variables just does not work for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `ajaxSubmit()`, you can pass a `context:` option. All the callbacks will be bound to this context:

```
$(".ajax-upload-image").submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        context: this,
        ...
    });
});
```

You will then be able to use `$(this)` and `this.id` in the callbacks to refer to the form that was submitted.